# Zend DB Adapter and Service manager

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have following in the configuration of a Zend project

```
            'db' => array(
                    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
                    'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=food;host=localhost',
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'driver_options' => array(
                            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                    )
            ),
            'service_manager' => array(
                    'factories' => array(
                            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                            => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
                    ),
            ),
```

I am trying to get DB adapter

> <strike>($adapter  = $adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');</strike>
>
> ( $adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

in a controller but is always stuck with.

> class: "Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException"
> file:
> " /path/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php"
> line: 909 message: "An exception was raised while creating
> "Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter"; no instance returned"

Comment: Your code looks okay apart from the unnecessary double `$adapter` assignment. Are there no other errors above the one you posted?

Comment: Oh, It was a typo, I tried writing code again! it is corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An exception was raised while creating "Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter"; no instance returned

This could be your problem. The `__construct` method can throw an `InvalidArgumentException`([docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Db.Adapter.Adapter.html)).
You should try to create an instance of `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` on your own and see if an exception is thrown.